# How to add custom block with image

Tags: magento2, custom-block

Add custom images div like this sample app block. How can we create it for our custom theme ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Cms/templates/new_block_1.phtml

```
<div class="block-with-image">
    <img class="image1" alt="image1" src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/homepage/your_image_name.png'); ?>">
</div>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content.top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="content-block1" template="Magento_Cms::new_block_1.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Or

to avoid the `xml` part, you can directly call your `phtml` where you want like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Cms::new_block_1.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: ok thanks this worked for me for home page but how can we re-use it as custom widgets and if you have any reference to learn about creating and customising theme in magento 2  it will be great.

Comment: you have to replace the `cms_index_index.xml` by the layout handle of your page, `cms_index_index.xml` is the layout handle of the home page for example